# How does java specify a color using new Color(int);?

Tags: java, colors, integer

Can anyone help me with this, I want to understand the math/reasoning java uses to pick colors behind this method.

Edit: This is now solved, idiot that I am, I forgot to actually use the doc.. Thanks people.

Comment: the official JDK is licensed under the GPL license, so you can just download the source and browse

Answer (score 0):

[API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int%29) says

> 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.

It works on [**RGB color**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) model, top 8 bits are turned to 1

```
value = 0xff000000 | rgb;
```